# Why "add subview" not work?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I try add subview but not work. My code is:

```
HomeViewController* homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
NSViewController *viewController = homeViewController;
[mainView addSubview: [viewController view]];
NSLog(@"%@",[viewController view]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[viewController view]superview]);
NSLog(@"%@",[mainView subviews]);
```

The NSLog write in console:

```
HTPC[1467:a0f] <HomeView: 0x10042e9f0>
HTPC[1467:a0f] (null)
HTPC[1467:a0f] (null)
```

Why addsubview don't work? When I run my app HomeView appears but I can't use it as subview.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like `mainView` is `nil` at the time this code is executed.

Comment: I'd agree; chances are he's doing this from an init method instead of from a viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib, etc.